# Le chrome et l'acier

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, connotation

Dans la chanson ["La vérité sur la vérité" (1977)](https://open.spotify.com/track/3KHvUnwgwxlYOMEP2oLBPk) Daniel Lavoie dit :

> Oh! les belles pensées, ça monte des bateaux
> Ça nous fait rêver
> Vivre pour toujours ton premier bec sucré
> M'aimeras-tu toujours, tu me l'as promis
> C'est la vie en dentelle aux rebords chromés

Mais dans [la version rééditée (2011)](https://open.spotify.com/track/27taysZXyVp9hOPOuFoyQg) il change le dernier vers :

> C'est la vie en dentelle aux rebords d'acier

1. Quelle est la connotation du mot "chromé" ? Comme je suis né dans les années 90 j'ai des difficultés à deviner ce que représentait cette matière pour les gens pendant les années 70. J'imagine que l'aspect technologique diminue l'effet de délicatesse de la dentelle ?
2. Pourquoi le transformer en "acier" ? Quelle en est la connotation? Le chrome est-il sorti du spotlight pour faire place à l'acier ? L'acier évoque peut-être mieux l'industrialisme, le brutalisme, etc?

P.S. Ça me fait aussi penser à l'album "Chrome Dreams" (écrit lui aussi en 1977 !) d'un autre chanteur canadien, Neil Young. Mais pour lui l'image a duré car il a fait un album appelé "Chrome Dreams II" en 2007.

Comment: Chromé ça évoque pour moi quelque chose de rutilant comme les grosses américaines des années 70, c'est l'aspect décoratif qui serait mis en avant, plus que la solidité. Je n'associe pas l'acier à l'aspect décoratif. L'acier est me semble-t-il un alliage qui contient, entre autres, du chrome. Faut-il vraiment voir de la symbolique ? Ne serait-ce pas juste l'envie de changer la rime ?

Comment: @None Peut-être, mais mon intuition dit qu'il aurait réexaminé cette image et pensé qu'elle aurait perdu quelque chose au cours des 35 ans intervenants, qu'elle ne dit pas à tout le monde ce qu'il avait voulu, tout comme elle ne dit pas trop pour moi sans que je réfléchisse ...

Comment: Je suis d'accord sur les connotations pour chrome, mais du coup, "années 70" fait un peu vieux en 2011, et encore plus maintenant. Si Lavoie avait laissé "chromé", la chanson serait un peu ringarde...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Chrome » a une association positive de beauté, par exemple (mais pas seulement) dans l'expression « [nickel chrome](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nickel_chrome) » déjà pas nouvelle en 1977. Les rebords chromés sont beaux, modernes et durs, je pense dans cet ordre. L'acier n'a pas du tout cette connotation : le seul point commun est la dureté, mais l'acier est fortement associé à l'industrie et à sa brutalité.

Hypothèse, mais que je ne sais pas comment confirmer sauf à demander à l'auteur : dès 1977, c'est l'aspect dur du chrome qu'il voulait mettre en valeur. Le chrome dur s'oppose à la dentelle douce. Dans la thématique de la chanson, il y a une opposition entre l'apparence et la réalité. Mais l'utilisation du chrome pour cette métaphore ouvrait une ambigüité non désirée : la « vie en dentelles aux rebords chromés » pourrait juste qualifier les dentelles avec un bord brillant comme du chrome. En changeant le chrome pour l'acier, cette interprétation disparaît et on a forcément une opposition entre doux et dur, entre beauté délicate et rigueur brutale.